# jQuery empty() listview

Tags: jquery, listview

I was wondering about how to empty a list in a proper way. Is it better to have a list in a div and then empty the div or the list?

I know this is a lame question but please help my understand this `empty()` function:)

**Case)**
What happens if I run this script:

```
$('#mylist).empty();
```

...on this list:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"><li>Hello!</li></ul>
```

Does it become:
A):

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"><li></li></ul>
```

Or does it become:
B):

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"></ul>
```

Or does it become just this:
C):

```
<ul></ul>
```

It looks like it becomes just this because next time I try to add stuff to my "mylist" list after I have run empty() on it. **I want it to still have the listview format** and not this:

```
 <ul></ul>.
```

**MyCode snippet:**

```
$('#mylist').empty();
var newlist = "<ul data-role=" + "'listview'" +" id=" + "'mylist'" + " data-inset=" + "'true'" + " data-theme=" + "'a'" + "><li>Hello!</li></ul>";
$('#mylist').append(newlist).listview().trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 5):

It becomes B). 
But as I understand, you problem is that listview styles are not applied to newly added list item. Take a look at [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-generated-listview)
According to it, you should do:

```
$('#mylist').empty();
var newlist = "<ul data-role=" + "'listview'" +" id=" + "'mylist'" + " data-inset=" + "'true'" + " data-theme=" + "'a'" + "><li>Hello!</li></ul>";
$('#mylist').append(newlist).listview("refresh").trigger('create');
```

See `.listview().` changed to `.listview("refresh").`.